# EasyMock capture mutable arg(collection)

Tags: java, java-8, easymock

I am using EasyMock.capture to capture collections passed to function. But that collection is mutable.

So if later on if function foo is modifying the collection it is also getting reflected inside the value captured by EasyMock. Is thee a way to force EasyMock to clone the collection in place of just keeping the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to manage such intermediate captures as such with `Easymock`, right now.

However, you can create your own capture type to facilitate this.

Here's something to get you started:

```
  public class DefensiveCopyCapture<T> extends Capture<T> {
    @Override
    public void setValue(T value) {
      // create a copy of your type here; 
      // if the type happens to be a Collection like in your case, use
      // the copy constructors to create a copy
      T copy = ...; 
      super.setValue(copy);
    }
  }
```

And then you can create captures like below and capture as many values as you want - the captured value collection will contain a snapshot of all the values captured at various times through out the course of the execution.

```
Capture<Type> capturer = new DefensiveCopyCapture<Type>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also retrieve the arguments using getCurrentArguments and IAnswer.

However, extending the Capture object is quite elegant too.